# How to correct skipping of numbers in a timer countdown in custom cell?

Tags: swift, uitableview, timer

In order to have a consistent implementation of a count down timer (counting down the recording time of audio) in each of my tableView cells, I placed a timer in a custom cell called 'createStoryCell' which is fired when 'countDownTime' is set.

```
class CreateStoryCell: UITableViewCell {

weak var delegate: createStoryCellDelegate?
var countDownTimer : Timer?

var countDownTime : Double! {
    didSet {
        startTimer()
    }
}

func startTimer() {

    countDownTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { (countDownTimer) in

        if self.countDownTime > 0.0 {
            self.countDown.isHidden = false
            self.countDownTime = self.countDownTime - 1.0
            self.countDown.text = String(self.countDownTime)
        } else {
            countDownTimer.invalidate()
        }
    }
  }
}
```

To set the countDownTime I use the following code in the 'cellForRowAt' in my viewController.

```
if storyItem?.isRecording == false {
            cell.record.setImage(UIImage(named: "smallMicBtn"), for: .normal)
            cell.countDown.isHidden = true
        } else {
            cell.countDownTime = 5.0
            cell.record.setImage(UIImage(named: "recordStop"), for: .normal)
        }
```

However, when I run the count down timer it skips numbers outputting only 4...2...0. I'd be grateful for any suggestions on how to avoid the skipping of 3 and 1. I have already tried to wrap the 'self.countDown.text = String(self.countDownTime)' in dispatchQueue.main.async but with the same result. Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: I think the problem was ` self.countDownTime = self.countDownTime - 1.0` line, did you debug this line for what is the `countDownTime` value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This

```
didSet {
    startTimer()
}
```

triggers every change of `countDownTime` here

```
self.countDownTime = self.countDownTime - 1.0
```

You shouldn't use `didSet`  , make it a method and call it once from `CellForRowAt`

---

Note also cells are dequeeud so after this line inside `CellForRowAt`  do

```
let cell  = ///
cell.countDownTimer?.invalidate()
```

in case user scrolls

Comment: Thanks for that. It worked. As suggested I created a method in the custom cell:       
func setCountDownTime(time: Double) {
        countDownTime = time
        startTimer()
    }  ---- I then called this from cellForRowAt with:                  
    cell.setCountDownTime(time: 5.0)

Comment: Your point on invalidating the countDownTimer in CellForRowAt was also very useful. Thanks again!